# How to get rid of Divide by Zero error in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, divide-by-zero

I have a dataframe that has two columns:

**df**

[image]

There are some scientific values like `0E-10`, I want create a new column such that:

`df["new_col"]=df["fruits_ratio"]/(df["fruits_ratio"]+df["vegetables_ratio"])`

But it give me an error like this:
    `DivisionByZero: [<class 'decimal.DivisionByZero'>]`

Is there a way to either replace the `0-E10` values or how can I avoid the error?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with "divide by zero" with pandas dataframes when manipulating columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886512/how-to-deal-with-divide-by-zero-with-pandas-dataframes-when-manipulating-colum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the float function will fix this for you `float()`. Assign the entire column as floats since most are already.

Comment: Float will handle dividing by zero?

Comment: Yes, well.. floats will produce `float('inf')` when dividing by zero in the context of a pandas series or dataframe division along an axis.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3], 'b':[0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0]})
```

as

```
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  0
3  3  1
4  0  1
5  1  0
6  2  1
7  3  0
```

Create a mask to identify where `a` or `b` is not zero which are safe to calculate on.

```
mask = (df['a'] != 0) | (df['b'] != 0)
```

the mask

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
```

Fill the result column with `NaN` then overwrite the ones you can calculate:

```
df['c'] = pd.np.NaN
df.loc[mask, 'c'] = df['a'] / (df['a'] + df['b'])
```

result

```
   a  b         c
0  0  0       NaN
1  1  1  0.500000
2  2  0  1.000000
3  3  1  0.750000
4  0  1  0.000000
5  1  0  1.000000
6  2  1  0.666667
7  3  0  1.000000
```

Applied to your question:

```
mask = (df['fruits_ratio'] != 0) | (df['vegetables_ratio'] != 0)
df['new_col'] = pd.np.NaN
df.loc[mask, 'new_col'] = df['fruits_ratio'] / (df['fruits_ratio'] + df['vegetables_ratio'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that pandas supports division by zero for columns with numeric dtype (such as float and int64) by returning a result of `inf`. However, for columns of object type, it raises a ZeroDivisionError exception.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72953622/18135454) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72953731/18135454) for examples.