# Why do I get infs when I divide by 0 in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, zero, divide-by-zero

All

I have two columns and I divide one by the other with colb being my denominator. When I divide one by the other however I get infs when there is 0 present in my colb e.g

```
df[cola]/df[colb]
```

Mathematically this is correct right? Just wondering if this is expected with pandas . Fir me it makes no sense to have these infs so I will probably replace with 0 but wanted to check

Comment: This is the expected result. `anything/0` is `inf`, except that `0/0` is `NaN`.

Comment: division by 0 is not defined. Check `df[colb]` beforehand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with "divide by zero" with pandas dataframes when manipulating columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886512/how-to-deal-with-divide-by-zero-with-pandas-dataframes-when-manipulating-colum)

Comment: Actually anything divided by 0 is undefined mathematically, it is not infinite

Comment: @Barmar `-anything/0` is `-inf` :)

Comment: `pandas` outputs `inf` because `positive/0` **approaches**  `inf`

Comment: Exactly as I thought thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For  x≠0 , and  x∈R , the limits of  x/0  as we approach from the left and right hand sides of  0  differ. Hence, it's not defined.

Consider approaching the limit from the right hand side. As the denominator gets smaller and smaller, the value will approach  ±∞  depending upon the sign of  x . If  x>0 , the limit will approach  ∞  and if  x<0 , the limit approaches  −∞ .

If we approach the limit from the left, if  x>0 , the limit approaches  −∞  and similarly  ∞  when  x<0 .

In both cases, there is a discontinuity when the denominator approaches  0  and hence  x/0  is undefined.

Hence, even in pandas this should yield. However, it is a convention that `x/0` is `inf` if `x>0`, `-inf` if `x<0`